# pandas :pd.date_range output error

Tags: python, loops, datetime, pandas, date-range

I have a data set with 3 columns `ID`, `vrddat`, `enddat` and 21000 rows.

```
ID       vrddat      enddat
```

```
1       2015.01.01  2015.01.03    
2       2015.03.01  2015.03.03
```

PS: Each ID can have multiple vrddat's and enddat's.

I need output as below:

```
ID      vrddat      enddat       day
```

```
1    2015.01.01   2015.01.03  2015.01.01
1    2015.01.01   2015.01.03  2015.01.02
1    2015.01.01   2015.01.03  2015.01.03
2    2015.03.01   2015.03.03  2015.03.01
2    2015.03.01   2015.03.03  2015.03.02
2    2015.03.01   2015.03.03  2015.03.03
```

I used following code to get above output

```
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    data_2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(row['vrddat'],row['enddat'], freq ='D'))
```

Using above code I get only 98 rows, but ideally output should contain way more rows than the input. Could any one suggest why I'm getting this kind of output. Is my code not iterating each and every row? How do I get `ID`, `vrddat` and `enddat` variables also in my output?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use first cast [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) both columns `vrddat` and `enddat` and then use [`itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for creating new expanding `DataFrame`. Last [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), but is necessary `ID` in `df` is unique.

```
df.vrddat = pd.to_datetime(df.vrddat)
df.enddat = pd.to_datetime(df.enddat)

df1 = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.ID,pd.date_range(r.vrddat, r.enddat)) for r in df.itertuples()])
        .reset_index()
df1.columns = ['day','ID']
print (df1)
         day  ID
0 2015-01-01   1
1 2015-01-02   1
2 2015-01-03   1
3 2015-03-01   2
4 2015-03-02   2
5 2015-03-03   2

print (pd.merge(df,df1, on='ID', how='left'))
   ID     vrddat     enddat        day
0   1 2015-01-01 2015-01-03 2015-01-01
1   1 2015-01-01 2015-01-03 2015-01-02
2   1 2015-01-01 2015-01-03 2015-01-03
3   2 2015-03-01 2015-03-03 2015-03-01
4   2 2015-03-01 2015-03-03 2015-03-02
5   2 2015-03-01 2015-03-03 2015-03-03
```

If `ID` is not unique, is possible use `unique` index for merging:

```
df.vrddat = pd.to_datetime(df.vrddat)
df.enddat = pd.to_datetime(df.enddat)
df = df.reset_index()

df1=pd.concat([pd.Series(r.index,pd.date_range(r.vrddat,r.enddat)) for r in df.itertuples()])
      .reset_index()
df1.columns = ['day','index']
print (df1)
         day  index
0 2015-01-01      0
1 2015-01-02      0
2 2015-01-03      0
3 2015-03-01      1
4 2015-03-02      1
5 2015-03-03      1

print (pd.merge(df,df1, on='index', how='left').drop('index', axis=1))
   ID     vrddat     enddat        day
0   1 2015-01-01 2015-01-03 2015-01-01
1   1 2015-01-01 2015-01-03 2015-01-02
2   1 2015-01-01 2015-01-03 2015-01-03
3   2 2015-03-01 2015-03-03 2015-03-01
4   2 2015-03-01 2015-03-03 2015-03-02
5   2 2015-03-01 2015-03-03 2015-03-03
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time out, your code is helpful Do you know why I'm getting only 98 rows in output? am I missing some logic?

Comment: I think you overwrite `data_2` in each loop, so get output of last loop - last row in `df`.